# How to call a inner/nested class with a function

Tags: python, class

I don't know if the title describes my problem correctly. Maybe it is a bit misleading.
I want to call the class Decoder within my Class ABC with the funtion func1 (that is inside my class ABC) but I can't get it work.

```
class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
        super(ABC, self).__init__()
        
    def func1(self):
        encoder=self.Encoder(1)
    
    class Encoder():
        def __init__(self, vocab_size):
            super(self.Encoder, self).__init__()
            self.vocab_size = vocab_size
f = ABC()
f.func1()
```

It gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2b76a7e09b6e> in <module>
     11             self.vocab_size = vocab_size
     12 f = ABC()
---> 13 f.func1()
     14 

<ipython-input-19-2b76a7e09b6e> in func1(self)
      4 
      5     def func1(self):
----> 6         encoder=self.Encoder(1)
      7 
      8     class Encoder():

<ipython-input-19-2b76a7e09b6e> in __init__(self, vocab_size)
      8     class Encoder():
      9         def __init__(self, vocab_size):
---> 10             super(self.Encoder, self).__init__()
     11             self.vocab_size = vocab_size
     12 f = ABC()

AttributeError: 'Encoder' object has no attribute 'Encoder'
```

I only used self.Encoder in the first place because PyCharm told me "Unsolved reference"
I then tried it without the self and got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-a9effce8ca1b> in <module>
     11             self.vocab_size = vocab_size
     12 f = ABC()
---> 13 f.func1()
     14 

<ipython-input-20-a9effce8ca1b> in func1(self)
      4 
      5     def func1(self):
----> 6         encoder=self.Encoder(1)
      7 
      8     class Encoder():

<ipython-input-20-a9effce8ca1b> in __init__(self, vocab_size)
      8     class Encoder():
      9         def __init__(self, vocab_size):
---> 10             super(Encoder, self).__init__()
     11             self.vocab_size = vocab_size
     12 f = ABC()

NameError: name 'Encoder' is not defined
```

How can I get this to work without removing the nested class structure?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ABC.Encoder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an inner class, `Encoder` can be considered a static variable on `ABC`. Consequently, you access it like any other static variable: `ABC.Encoder`:

```
class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
        super(ABC, self).__init__()
    def func1(self):
        encoder=ABC.Encoder(1)
    
    class Encoder():
        def __init__(self, vocab_size):
            super(ABC.Encoder, self).__init__()
            self.vocab_size = vocab_size
```

Keep in mind that `self`, when it's the first parameter of an instance method, refers to the *instance* that the method is being called on, not the *class*. It's generally considered poor practice to call static methods on an instance (though you can use `instance.__class__.method()` as a workaround if you really need to, that's almost never necessary because you almost always know which class's statics you want to invoke).